# How to get table content and send it to the server side via AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to to get all of the content of one table (html), is it possible to get all of its rows from the other side and to send them into a post request to the server server. But I wasn't able to find how to deal with this. Do I need to bind each row using `ng-model` or how, please?

Here is my html table

```
<html>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</html>
```

The table contains about 1000 rows in real.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add AngularJS to the title of your post.

Comment: Where is the angular part of your code? Why do you start a <th> tag and close it with a </td>. In angular you have to construct the table with a ng-repeat directive. Maybe you should read some tutorials?

Comment: @mainguy, you're right about th and td, it was a typo. I'm in fact loading that content via a PHP loop.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it much better, this should be <td>s and not header cells. Apart from this I am still missing the angular part. You don't have to send any html code from your php script. All you need is some json encoded data. That's why angular is called a MVC framework, Your server sided php is the Model (M). Its controlled by a controller (C) in js and rendered to a table by the view (V) which is basically a template engine. So show us some output of your php script.

Comment: @mainguy, it should be better now

Comment: @mainguy, I'm not sending html data using php scripts. But, I'm sending php models to view.

Comment: Aw, come on. Show us some of your code already. And not just a useless piece of wrong html code. How do you expect that anyone may have an answer for you if you keep the issue as a secret?

Comment: @user1835565 No, AngularJS should not be in the title. That's exactly what the tags are for.

Comment: Oh, ok. Never saw it. Not very visible though. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by the table content.
If you really just want to send the actual HTML contents, you could use jQuery to get the contents of the table and send it over using ajax.

```
var contents = $("#tableId").html();
var dto = {
   TableContents: contents
};

$http({ method: "POST", url: "yourUrlHere", data: JSON.stringify(dto) })
.success(function (response) {
   alert("Woot!!!");
});
```

If you're trying to read the value of each cell and then send it over the wire, that can be done too though it's slightly more involved. If you're trying to do that, let me know and I can walk you through it.

Comment: That way I'm sending a row html content. I'm jus trying to send the content of that table and to browse it. For example, `tab[0]['A']` gets back 1.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to construct an array of your table data then and send it in the same fashion as shown above. So, loop through the contents of each <td> and add them to an array.